# Check input value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I have json array and I want to check the value of input filed is present or not in array.

```
<input type='text'id='seat_number' name='seat_number' ng-model="employeeData.new_seat_number">
```

My array is `employeeData.seat_array`.

How to do it with Angular?

```
$scope.$watch('employeeData.new_seat_number', function (newVal) {
    console.log(newVal);

    $.each(employeeData, function (i, obj) {
        if (obj.seat_number === $scope.employeeData.new_seat_number) {
            alert("asd");
        }
    });

});
```

Array structure:

```
[{"seat_number":"834"},{"seat_number":"8F3"},{"seat_number":"891"}]
```

Comment: you most cases you not need in jquery when use angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found easy solution

```
$scope.checkc = function(){


        if(($scope.employeeData.seat_array.indexOf($scope.employeeData.new_seat_number))>-1)
        {
            alert('New seat number not available');
            $scope.employeeData.new_seat_number="";
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
var inArray = $scope.employeeData.seat_array.indexOf($scope.employeeData.new_seat_number) > -1;
```

I'm not sure about the structure of the `employeeData.seat_array` but if it's array of objects you could use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of indexOf:

```
var inArray = $scope.employeeData.seat_array.some(function(obj) {
    return obj.seat_number === $scope.employeeData.new_seat_number;
});
```

Comment: seems like it not work, because in _seat_array_ objects instead _seat_numbers_

Comment: Makes sense, in this case `some` might do the job.

Comment: Updates array structer @dfsq